# Check if activity is visible (onResume&Pause dosen't suit, because of multiwindow mode)

Tags: java, android, android-7.0-nougat, android-7.1-nougat, multi-window

I need to ensure somehow the activity is on screen visible to user eyes.

We can do this by listetning to onResume & onPause events in Activity class and setting some boolean in these functions.

But onPause is called not only when you minimize your activity, onPause is also called when you switched to other window in multiwindow mode (Android 7.x Nougat)

So the boolean onPause&onResume method will lead to mistakes.

Then how to know visibility of Activity?

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On `Nougat` and above you must check the `onStop` method , it will tell you when your `Activity` is not visible , you could use this code:

```
@Override
public void onPause() {
  super.onPause();
  if (Build.VERSION..SDK_INT <= 23) {
    //your activity is not visible
    onHidden();
  }
}
@Override
public void onStop() {
  super.onStop();
  if (Build.VERSION..SDK_INT > 23) {
    //your activity is not visible
    onHidden();
  }
}
```

Assuming that your `onHidden`  method will perform some action.

I found this interesting link about your problem: [Multiwindow](https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/android-activity-lifecycle-onStop/)

Comment: thanks, that works, besides I've added this in onPause:

`if ( activity.isInMultiWindowMode() == false ) onHidden()`

, may be handy when for example tap on facebook messaneger bubble